# Issue with Sql Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, inner-join

i have a issue on sql server 2008, i have 2 tables SlideShow and Slide. common field in both the table is SlideShowId.
now to get all the SlideShow with SlideCount i use this procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAllSlideShow]
    @FILTER BIT,
    @PORTALID INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@FILTER = 1)
        SELECT SS.SLIDESHOWNAME + ' [' + CAST((COUNT(S.SLIDEID)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))+']', SS.SLIDESHOWID FROM SLIDESHOW SS
        INNER JOIN SLIDES S
        ON SS.SLIDESHOWID = S.SLIDESHOWID
        WHERE SS.PORTALID = 0 AND [TYPE] IS NULL
        GROUP BY SS.SLIDESHOWNAME, SS.SLIDESHOWID
    ELSE
        SELECT SS.SLIDESHOWNAME + ' [' + CAST((COUNT(S.SLIDEID)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))+']', SS.SLIDESHOWID FROM SLIDESHOW SS
        INNER JOIN SLIDES S
        ON SS.SLIDESHOWID = S.SLIDESHOWID
        WHERE SS.PORTALID = @PORTALID
        GROUP BY SS.SLIDESHOWNAME, SS.SLIDESHOWID
END
```

this runs fine, but say if new slideshow has been created, this procedure does not show up that slideshow until new slide has been created in that slideshow, actually that is because i have joined both the tables for SlideCount, and there is no slide for particular slideshow, that slideshow wont show up, but i also want that slideshow. the count in that should be 0 by default.

is there any way i can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using an `INNER JOIN`.  An `INNER JOIN` will only show results that are equal in both tables, so if your slideshow record was added to only one table then the `INNER JOIN` would not pull it in the `SELECT`.  Try changing your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @Abbas no problem, and those are the types of things that a second set of eyes always helps.  Glad to help.